# how to deny delete/rename/move root(or other) node(s) in jsTree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

for example:

```
[{
"data": "reference",
"attr": {
    "id": "0"
},
"state": "open",
"children": [
    [{
        "data": "one",
        "attr": {
            "id": "1"
        },
        "state": "closed"
    }, {
        "data": "two",
        "attr": {
            "id": "2"
        }
    }]
]
}, {
"data": "recycle bin",
"attr": {
    "id": "bin"
},
"state": "closed",
"children": []
}]
```

i need to deny delete/move/rename "reference" & "recycle bin" nodes with "dnd", "crrm" and "context menu" plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For avoiding moves using the [crrm plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm) you could do:

```
"crrm": {
   "move": {
      "check_move": function(m) { return (m.o[0].id !== "0" && m.o[0].id !== "bin"); }
   }
}
```

In summary, you need to return TRUE for allowing the move, or FALSE otherwise. So you check that the node's ID being moved is not the **reference** one, or the **recycle bin** one.

Please take a look at the [jsTree documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation) for accomplishing the other tasks, as everything you need is there. Don't be lazy :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not lazy :) I'm inattentive.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture node delete event and check for node's metadata:

```
.bind('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    // Check medatada, assuming that root's parent_id is NULL:
    if (data.rslt.obj.attr('parent_id') == null) {
       alert('Root folder is here to stay.');
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       return false;
    }
})
```